# Redux-saga cannot use generator function inside promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I'm a newbie to redux-saga. Currently I'm working on a simple login example.
Take a look at these function:

```
function sendLoginRequest(data) {
  const headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json' };
  const url = LOGIN_URL;
  const serialize = new FormData(data.event.target);
  const loginData = {
    username: serialize.get('email'),
    password: serialize.get('password'),
    client_secret: APP_SECRET_KEY,
    client_id: APP_SECRET_ID,
    grant_type: PASSWORD_GRANT_TYPE,
    scope: '*',
  }

  return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: loginData,
    headers: headers,
  });
}

export function* loginRequest(data) {
  yield takeLatest(LOGIN_REQUEST, data => {
    const response = sendLoginRequest(data);
    console.log(response);
    response
      .then(function* (data) {
        console.log(data);
        yield put(LOGIN_SUCCESS, data.data);
      })
      .catch(function* (err) {
        console.log(err);
        yield put(LOGIN_FAILURE, err.response);
      });
  });
}
```

It's work perfect if I run middleware like this:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);
sagaMiddleware.run(loginRequest);
```

But then I add a new rootSaga:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(loginRequest),
        fork(loginSuccess),
    fork(loginFailure)
    ]);
}
```

And I run the rootSaga instead of loginRequest saga:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

And now these new code doesn't work at all.
when I try to `console.log(response);` in loginRequest generator function, it's shown that the promise has been resolved. And it doesn't run the then-catch.

Can anyone help me clear this out?
Thank you~

Comment: I don't understand why have you used `all` effect here, what about 

  export default function* rootSaga() {
          yield fork(loginRequest);
          yield fork(loginSuccess);
          yield fork(loginFailure);
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
export function* loginRequest(data) {
  yield takeLatest(LOGIN_REQUEST, data => {
    const response = yield call(sendLoginRequest, data);

    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        yield put(LOGIN_SUCCESS, data.data);
        return;
    }
    yield put(LOGIN_FAILURE, err.response);
  });
}
```

The thing to note is `sendLoginRequest` returns a promise.  `redux-saga` is designed to work with promises **without** using `.then()`.  You can `yield call()` any function that returns a promise and `redux-saga` will wait for the promise to resolve before executing the next line of code.